# Cannot post: question duplicate of a previous question accidentally asked (then intentionally deleted) using the wrong account

Tags: support

I have two accounts on SE. I wanted to post a question in musicfans.stackexchange.com but later realized it was posted with the wrong account, which I also realized I didn't want later on. I then immediately deleted the question, logged in with my regular account (which, I wonder why, didn't happen right after I created my new account at musicfans) and asked the question again. Now the question is flagged as a duplicate of my deleted question and the [link](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/2502/whats-the-meaning-of-agnes-obels-beast) points to a dead end (404).

What can I do to post my question anyway?

Comment: You should get your accounts merged. There really is no reason to have two accounts.

Comment: I have a perfectly valid reason to keep both.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/35607/236364 If it is a valid reason, you have nothing to worry about, however it can easily lead you to violating SE rules.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Indeed none of my accounts are meant to overlap... except in case of human mistake, which in this case occurred from being mislead by SE registration itself. Maybe some old login cookie lurking around, I don't know. The cat won't be caught in the same trap again ;-) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the system, you haven't asked any questions on Music Fans.  So, if it's being automatically marked as a dupe, it's doing so at the Stack Exchange level.

I would ask this over on the main [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com) and see if a main mod can help.  From our level, we can't change anything like that.

An alternative would be to change some of the wording.  I think questions that are 99% identical get flagged before they're even posted, and that's probably what's happening.

Comment: Argh :-D . I did indeed ask on the main meta; I have been downvoted and directed here. That is also my first question on musicfans so it's logical there's no trace of me here (yet). But thanks for the suggestion, I'll try to "defeat" the system by changing the wording at some point if the issue persists. (Funny avatar, BTW!)

Comment: My only option was to change wording as the deleted question still raised a duplicate stopper. Problem solved.